# copying files into a docker container from Rust

Tags: docker, rust

I am trying to write a Rust program which uses `Command` to copy some files inside a docker container. The code is shown below:-

```
Command::new("cmd").arg("/C")
        .arg(&format!("docker cp {file_name} {container}:/home/", container=&container_name, file_name=&source_file))
        .spawn()
        .expect("command failed")
```

The variable `source_file` is an absolute path to a file and `container_name` is the name of the container. The issue is this code works normally for all cases except for the fact when I have **blank spaces** on the path.

Like for example for the input:-

```
let source_file = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2021\file";
```

On running the program with above input, I get the following message on the terminal and the file is not copied to the container.

```
`"docker cp" requires exactly 2 arguments`.
```

Is there a way to modify the input file path in the input side such that docker cp accepts blank spaces in file paths in Windows through the above program?

Comment: its probably better to copy the files during build or use a volume

Comment: The code you show is vulnerable to a _shell injection attack_; this is a security problem that can come up whenever you try to construct a command line using a string.  Prefer passing commands broken up into individual words; or better, use the Docker SDK rather than calling the `docker` CLI tool; or better still, rework your program so you don't need to copy files into it after it starts (how would you copy a file into this running Rust program?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's relatively straight forward if you don't pass it through `cmd` which doesn't do much and makes things complicated here:

```rust
Command::new("docker")
        .arg("cp")
        .arg(source_file) // might need `.to_string()` on `source_file` if it doesn't implement `AsRef<OsStr>` already
        .arg(format!("{container_name}:/home/"))
        .spawn()
        .expect("command failed")
```

Comment: This works for me. Will it be possible to chain more commands like exec with this command?